# DB2 iSeries Trigger for added & modified timestamp and user fields

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Perhaps triggers are not needed for added/modifed dates, maybe there are appropriate functions to set their values, in any case:

My question is with the following fields,

```
created (timestamp)
updated (timestamp)
createdBy (string, to hold the created by user name)
updatedBy (string, to hold the updated by user name)
```

how do I alter the table such that on creation and update these fields hold the appropriate values?

**Edit**: I now just need to know how to set the updatedBy and updated timestamp fields each time the record is accessed.

Comment: Okay I see that the created field is addressed by the use of timestamp alone, the default value is the time of insertion. One down...

Comment: "createdBy CHAR(30) DEFAULT USER,"  takes care of the createdBy field... Two more to go.

Comment: This tutorial has answered my datetime trigger questions http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1612640-update-trigger-update-time-column.html, I'll probably self answer in a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following table for a reference:

```
create table test(                    
  id integer generated always as identity,    
  content char(60),                           
  createdBy char(30) default user,            
  created timestamp default current timestamp,
  updatedBy char(30),                         
  updated timestamp default null,             
  primary key(id)                             
)
```

This table has an auto incrementing primary key (id), a createdBy field which is set on insert, a created timestamp which is set on insert now we just need triggers to make the last two work as expected (there is a new feature to set updated on update without the use of triggers but the feature does not seem to allow a null value to show the record has never been updated so that does not work for me).

```
insert into test (content) VALUES ('first thing'),
  ('second thing')
```

To see that the default values for created and createdBy have been set:

```
select * from test
```

To add update triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger                   
  NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE ON test 
  REFERENCING NEW AS post                  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW                   
SET                                        
 post.updated = CURRENT TIMESTAMP,         
 post.updatedBy = USER
```

To see if the above is working, lets update the values in "content":

```
update co05arh/test
  set content = 'first thing updated'
  where id = 1
```

To see the new default values

```
select * from co05arh/test
```

We should then see something like

```
ID  CONTENT                 CREATEDBY   CREATED                     UPDATEDBY   UPDATED
1   first thing updated     KEN         2011-04-29 16:16:17.942429  KEN         2011-04-29 16:16:28.649543
2   second thing            KEN         2011-04-29 16:16:18.01629   <null>      <null>
```